# How to update input file before actual DITA OT processing begins

Tags: xslt, ant, dita-ot

I want to update topicref element values dynamically before DITA OT preprocessing starts.

I have created an xsl file with a template which match the ditamap element and update the node values. That xsl file I have added in a target and that target I have added in the preprocessing target(<target name="preprocess" depends="preprocess.init,**updatemap**,.../>). But this did not help me to update the map.

Please guide me the steps which I need to follow to update the map.

DIT OT version 3.7.1
plugin xhtml

Comment: Can you describe more your usecase? Maybe give a small example?

Comment: I am trying to add copy-to attribute with values dynamically before the DITA OT processing starts. Two reason I want to avoid the manual update, Existing ditamap user need to spent time and  also I want to restrict the copy-to usage only for one transformation type.

Comment: There is a publishing parameter which automatically generates unique file names if a topic is referenced multiple times in the DITA Map: https://www.dita-ot.org/dev/parameters/parameters-base.html#base__force-unique
And there is also this extension point which may be useful: https://www.dita-ot.org/dev/topics/migrating-to-3.5.html#migrating-to-3.5__rewriting-output-files
Other than that, there is a "copy-to" stage in the build files, ideally you would place your custom target just before it gets called but I do not see an extension point for that.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I am able to update the input map. Before I modify the <topicref> I am applying a template with deep copy of nodes and attribute, this is actually adding all the dita classes in to the ditamap elements. Is there any way to copy as is the original ditamap and apply the custom template which I created?
<xsl:template match='@* | node() | comment()'>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node() | comment()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>